# RStudio, apply function by column class

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I would like to apply a Function(KGE) to my data (column R and RM by column ens(class 1, 2, 3, 4,..).

example, if I want to apply the KGE for class one I use KGE(mydata$R[1:13],mydata$RM[1:13]), but I don't wanna have to repeat the same operation several times, can you please tell how I can apply my function considering the classes of my ens column ?
Im joining the datase to the post.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the data using `dput()` instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data to verify that this will indeed work, but this `dplyr` solution should do it.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%            # the pipe operator makes this the first argument of the next function
  group_by(ens) %>% # groups by the ens variable so whatever happens next happens by group
  summarize(across(starts_with("R"), # apply the function to all columns that start with R
                   KGE,              # the function to apply
                   .names = "{col}_{fn}"))   # makes column names
```

You should get an output like this:

```
  ens   R_KGE  RM_KGE
1   1   A           B
2   2   C           D
3   3   E           F
4   4   G           H
```

where A-H are the outputs of the function.